# GitLab: Adding changes to directory that doesn't exist yet

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm starting a new project on GitLab.
I have some libraries from other projects that I wanna add to this project, but I also wanna make some modifications to those libraries. When I commit and request a merge, I wanna be able to see the differences made to those libraries.
The thing is, I have the unmodified version of those libraries, and I have the modified ones as well.
How can I push the clean libraries (that require no review) and then push the modified library files to the same branch without losing my modifications (which seems to happen when I checkout that branch after adding the unmodified libraries)?

Comment: Why dont you just dont you just push the original files first and then make modification and push those too. In that way you will have two commits for the same files with old and new. You can see/compare both on any merge too like kdiff3.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to temporarily put your files in a different folder :

```
mv lib/thatlib lib/thatlib.myversion
git checkout other/branch
rm -rf lib/thatlib
mv lib/thatlib.myversion lib/thatlib
```

---

One way to change the active commit without checking out its content is `git reset` :

```
git checkout -b tmpbranch    # create a throwaway branch
git reset other/branch       # move that throwaway branch to 'other/branch'
git checkout other/branch    # set the active branch to 'other/branch'
git branch -d tmpbranch      # delete the throwaway branch
```